# NoReverseMatch error, trying to set up a detailed page view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to set a detailed page, so that every time a person clicks on a link to an article, it will take them to a detailed page about that article. I feel like the error is somewhere in my `urls.py` or the actual url in my `list.html` file.

Update #1 
- Changed FullArticle_detailed to detailed in urls.py
- I get prompted with a NoReverseMatch error, which highlights line 26 in my `list.html`

```
Reverse for 'detailed' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>\\S+)$']
```

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Here's a screenshot of my Sublime:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mismatch in the url `name`:

in the template you are using `detailed`, but in the `urls.py` there is `FullArticle_detailed`.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what I should be changing.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen replace `FullArticle_detailed` with `detailed` in the `urls.py`.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried that. And I end up with: Reverse for 'detailed' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>\\S+)$']

Comment: @AndrewNguyen good, now we see a different problem. `object.slug` is empty for that object - that's why it is not matching the url.